# How to populate a "Favourite" section in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create a UITableView with 2 sections:

The first (upper) section lists entries from the second section that have been marked as "favourite".
*) The user shall be able to choose an entry, which results in the dismissal of the UITableView
*) Deselect an entry as favourite

The second (lower) section lists entries with a title and a subtitle.
The user shall be able to 
a) choose an entry - which results in the dismissal of the UITableView
b) Select/Deselect an entry as favourite - which leaves the UITableView on screen, copying the selected entry into the "favourite" (first) section.

My questions:

- Are there any best UI/UX practices on iOS to achieve this (IMHO rather standard) behaviour?
- And/Or do I have to manually create a custom UITableViewCell with an UIImageView (for the "favourite" icon), and two labels (for title and subtitle), and attach a Tap gesture recognizer to the UIImageView?

I'd prefer not to create a separate "Edit" state for the table view, letting the user rearrange the order - all I want is either select an entry, or toggle favourite on/off.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UITableViewCell` `accessoryView` property to add your button / image view. You can use either a gesture or a target/action to be notified about selection.